# Why is nhibernate looking in /bin/debug for the hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class library with all my nhibernate code (domain/mappings using fluent).

Now I am just doing some simple tests in a console application, and I am getting an error saying it can't find the configruation file in /bin/debug

I have the file in /consoleTests/hibernate.cfg.xml

Why would it be looking in the /bin/debug folder of the console application?

Answer (score 5):

If you are calling the `Configure()` method without any parameters, then I believe that the `hibernate.cfg.xml` must be in the same directory as the application that uses it.

When you compile your project, it gets compiled to the `bin/debug/` directory. When you run your project (by either clicking on it or debugging it in Visual Studio), the working directory is `bin/debug/`, so that is where the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is expected to be.

You could:

- use a post-build event within Visual Studio to copy the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file to the output directory
- call `Configure(path)`, where `path` is the path to your `hibernate.cfg.xml` in your `/consoleTests/` directory.

Have a look at "[A fluent interface to NHibernate - Part 4 - Configuration](http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/08/25/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate---part-4---configuration.aspx)" for more detailed information on how to configure NHibernate.

Comment: Change the properties for the hibernate.cfg.xml to "copy always" or "copy if newer" and it will be copied to the output path.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the xml property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always"

Answer (score 0):

That's the current directory when running in Visual Studio.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: what do you mean?  I am just running the console application from within vs.net....

Comment: @Homestead: Adrianbanks gave the full answer to that.